# Remove the spacing on the left of a section title

Tags: spacing, titles, sections-paragraphs

I'm using this to modify my \section, \subsection and \subsubsection commands:

```
%Sections
\makeatletter
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}
          {\z@}{10pt minus 0pt}{10pt minus 0pt}{\textbf}}
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}
          {\z@}{10pt minus 0pt}{10pt minus 0pt}{\textbf}}
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}
          {\z@}{10pt minus 0pt}{10pt minus 0pt}{\normaltext}}
\def\thesection{\arabic{section}.\hskip -1ex}   
\def\thesubsection {\thesection\hskip 1.1ex \arabic{subsection}\hskip -1ex}
\def\thesubsubsection {\thesubsection\hskip 1.1ex .\arabic{subsubsection}\hskip -1ex}
\makeatother
```

But I have a space on the left of my section title that I would like to remove. I've made a beautiful picture to ilustrate my case:

[image: Isn't it beautiful?]

What I want is to align the section title along with the bigger bar.

Do you think you can help me remove that space?

Thanks!

Comment: I would *not* redefine `\thesection` (and friends) the way you do, since this will affect the references as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a font switch `\bfseries` rather than a macro `\textbf` and `\normalfont` rather than `\normaltext` (which doesn't exist).